# Get a list of objects and then add more objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i have a list of static buildings, that i get simply by Building.all. A city has many buildings, so i would actually like to get a list of all building objects, accompanied by a list of their city_building objects.

The associations are (simple language):

```
city has_many buildings
city has_many city_buildings(city_id,building_id) (through buildings)
```

I would like to get a list like :

```
Building1 => nil (building does not exist in the city)
Building2 => city_building1
Building3 => city_building2
Building4 => nil
```

What is an efficient way of doing this without having to get all the buildings and then loop again for each city_building ?

Comment: Can a building belong to more than one city?  That seems weird, but if not, why do has_many :through?  Anyway, I'd like to see the other side of the relationship.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, i found the solution myself, i guess it will be helpful to some, so i write it here :

```
Building.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN city_buildings ON city_buildings.building_id = buildings.id").includes(:city_building)
```

Answer (score 0):

Building.include({ :city_building => [:city] }).where('cities.name = ?', 'Foo').all

UPDATE: Note, I updated the above answer after the first comment explained a requirement I had not realized was part of the initial request)

Does that do what you're after?

Comment: Not really, this does not specify a city. I want to do this, but for a particular city.

Comment: Not really. This just returns what city.city_buildings would return. Only those buildings that the city has and not a list of all buildings whether the city has them or not.